# Override file in ember addon

Tags: ember.js, add-on

I need to override this method:
normalize(payload, modelName)

in ember-cli-mirage addon and serializer-registry file

https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage/blob/master/addon/serializer-registry.js#L21

I have no idea where to put file to override it in my ember project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to override it for all serializers or just one?

If all, you could so something like this on the application serializer:

```js
// mirage/serializers/application.js
import { JSONAPISerializer } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default JSONAPISerializer.extend({

  normalize(payload, modelName) {
    // This is how to call "super"
    let jsonApiDocument = JSONAPISerializer.prototype.serialize.apply(this, arguments);

    // Tweak the document

    return jsonApiDocument;
  }

});
```

Note that `normalize()` is only used by POST and PUT shorthands.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to override it for all serializers, thank you for response, that was helpful for me.